# Adding Helpers in Handlebar Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, helper, handlebarshelper

I am using HandleBar in Scala using [HandleBar](https://github.com/mwunsch/handlebars.scala) module to create a HandleBar template. Currently, I am not able to render *href* link

```
  <a href="{{URL}}">
```

> URL

is not getting rendered even though I am passing it correctly. They have a helper example which is not clear.

Is there a way to render this URL properly. I am new to HandleBar.

Comment: Can you add more information on how your rendering this page? I see play framework tagged but wondering more about your setup for serving a frontend page. Are you using play frameworks scala templates? Something else? How are you passing `url`?

Comment: I am building mail-templates using handleBar in Scala Play-Framework.

Comment: Please add some code here. Specially the Scala code that renders the template.